# Facebook Share doesn't show my description or my thumbnail

Tags: html, facebook-sharer

I have followed every single piece of advice I have found to try to get this to work but all of it has been to no avail. Can someone tell me why my description/thumbnail doesn't show up? Thanks. Below is my code and the link to the site:

Meta Tags:

```
<meta name="title" content="La Vita è Bella, because life is beautiful" />
<meta name="description" content="Drawing on Italy’s most famous export – great-tasting, healthy, colourful food – La Vita é Bella brings families together to experience mealtimes the Italian way." />

<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/images/imageforfacebook.jpg" />
```

Actual Link:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src='../images/share/s-fb.png' /></a>
```

http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To those (like me) for whom the other answer did not work:

In the `<head>` and `</head>`section, add

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mathnuggets.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.mathnuggets.com/images/fb-logo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Math website for your gifted student" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Challenging word problems for gifted elementary students" />`
```

Then go to [FB Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and enter your URL there to refresh FB's cache of your page.

^^^  Refreshing the cache is important.

Comment: I used below tags:
<meta property="og:url" content="http://72.5.167.17:8003/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://72.5.167.17:8003/img/header-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is my description" />

Title and Description successfully changed, but image is still not coming.

Comment: @Gaurav123, is the 72.5.167.17:8003 accessible from the internet or is that only for your local env? Can you access it through the FB Linter?  What error does Linter give you?

Comment: Yes its accessible (from internet) http://72.5.167.17:8003/img/header-logo.png.
I did not get any error, but the image was not replaced.
Image size was 526px * 361px , but its displaying that image size should be atleast 200px*200px

Answer (score 92):

--2nd EDIT--

Please note that this answer doesn't work any more and is out of date. Please try [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910232/104223).

-- ORIGINAL ANSWER--

Got it sorted. Had to use a url that is chock full of craziness:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s= 100&amp;p[title]=La Vita È Bella&amp;p[url]=http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/teachers/resources.html&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.lavitaebella.co.uk/images/imageforfacebook.gif&amp;p[summary]=Drawing on Italy’s most famous export – great-tasting, healthy, colourful food – La Vita é Bella brings families together to experience mealtimes the Italian way"><img src='../images/share/s-fb.png' /></a>
```

--EDIT--

As some extra information, I can't remember where I originally found this information but here's what the s=100 part means:

> The basic approach is you are providing a link to http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100 which is the basic share page (typically this is shown in a popup).

But I tried changing the numbers and it still goes to the same place.

As for the `&amp;p`, it's just html code for &p and I think this is the array that Facebook dissects to get at the information.

Comment: Epic!  Been looking for this answer like crazy.  Thanks!

Comment: Dude, you deserve way more up-votes. This helped me out quite a lot.

Comment: great post, much appreciated!

Comment: Any idea how to add a redirect_uri and/or close a share popup after the user shares? (I tried adding [redirect_uri] to the end of the string, but no go. Thanks!

Comment: Folks I have a question: @Drew has given in his answer the path to a single image file through p[images][0]="<URL>"... I need to give multiple images, how do I do that? I tried p[images][0]="<URL1>"&amp;p[images][1]="<URL2>" but it didn't work

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working now.  I was able to get it to work using the og:title, etc. meta tags though.  Had to ping it with the FB linter to get it to refresh though.

Comment: Following the aforementioned method, I've added successfully a link to a Flash application by using the href parameters. Heaven, after not being able to make the 'og:blah' metatags work.

Comment: Facebook just changed how sharing is supposed to work and the above method no longer leads to expected results. It seems that using metatags with the `property="og:title"` is the only way of doing it right.

Comment: Its not working anymore. Can anyone suggest other way?

Comment: I think you should add the disclaimer that it isn't working anymore to the top of the post.