# share an url with multiple url variables using facebook sharer.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I have an url i would like users to share using facebook sharer.php

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=$title>&p[summary]=$descp&p[images][0]=$image&p[url]=$url)
```

where `$ur`l is the url i would like to share. the structure of my url is as follows

http://mydomain.com/index.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2

...apparently, facebook seems to scrap out the rest of the url after encountering the 1st '&' on my url.

Decoding the url din't help either. Is there a way i can pass the full url plus the variables in it to be shared with the rest of the details?

Comment: "Make sure you URL encode the u and t parameters" - See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ towards the bottom under "Creating Your Own Share URL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `&` to `&amp;`. 
This worked for me: [Facebook Share doesn't show my description or my thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950189/facebook-share-doesnt-show-my-description-or-my-thumbnail)

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. Tried it before I came searching for a solution. The other answer does, however.

Answer (score 6):

Send your entire url encoded. So `&` of your url will be replaced with `%26`. I found it. Thanks for your question.

Comment: This one works. The accepted answer doesn't work. I didn't even have to encode the entire URL, I just had to change `&variable=value` to `%26variable=value`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use URL encoding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

It seems you are using PHP, so you can simply use urlencode($url) when you construct the sharer URL (instead of just $url).