# Facebook Like button - fetches "wrong" image

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm using the following code to add a Facebook like button to my site:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=XXXXXXXX&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When I later look at my wall I can see the post that I've just liked. But it shows a gui-widget (from the sites grafik) not any other "valid" images. Is it possible to specify which image to show?

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to use [open graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) (namely `<og:image>`) to specify what image you want to show.

Additionally, you can use the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to debug what you're sending Facebook. You may have some issues with the linter as it *says* it decaches when you lint a URL, but in practice it doesn't always work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide metadata at the page you're liking that will populate the image.

Check this out: [Want custom title / image / description in facebook share link from a flash app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400947/want-custom-title-image-description-in-facebook-share-link-from-a-flash-app/3852415#3852415)

In the example provided the page returns metadata that allows Facebook to set the description, caption, and image for the object (your page) being liked.