# Meta descriptions of frontpage items not working in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

When I view the page source the meta tags are fine, however when I try to share the website link (the problem is only with frontpage item) on Facebook, the preview points to "Joomla! ..." text.

I have also changed

1. Changed the global config file (that only ensures all other pages work fine except the frontpage item)
2. hardcoding the MetaDesc tag in *.php files.

Maybe I'm missing something very basic?

Comment: Hey, I noticed your Google problem is gone already. On facebook, it's still pretty much nothing but in plus.google.com we're getting a better result. I would say your problems are, (a) No H1 tag as far as I can tell (b) no image tag anywhere near the top of your code. Make an h1 tag and put an image in there (hide it with css if you dont need it) (c) You need to clean up your header, search engines etc don't parse more than a 100 words. facebook and all give this a lot of priority. Would also appreciate it if you accept or vote up my answer below (or the comments that were helpful at least).

Comment: hey, I've updated my answer to include the solution for the facebook problem. Would also appreciate an accept.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the Generator meta tag from Joomla? The only meta data tag I know of that starts Joomla! is the generator tag. In Joomla 1.6 onwards you can remove this by adding a line to your template. In 1.5 however you have to edit the following file.

```
\libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer ~ line 84
```

As mentioned earlier, the Google problem should be solved by waiting for a while.
Facebook seems to need custom meta tags in order to work properly. There is a thread about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400947/want-custom-title-image-description-in-facebook-share-link-from-a-flash-app). Also worthwhile checking out [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) section.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot or something of issue? If the Generator tag is not on the page there is no reason for that text to show up. I have noticed that Facebook does tend to do some caching of URL's so perhaps copy the URL into Facebook with some sort of cache buster in the URL like http://google.com/index.php?cachebuster=369

Comment: when i try putting the link in facebook it shows welcome to front page
Joomla! - the dynamic portal engine and content management system

Comment: http://autismwithattitude.com/, this is my url, when i try pasting on facebook wall, it shows joomla description

Comment: http://autismwithattitude.com/
even, if i try pasting this in google.com, again the joomla description comes up. can you help me with this??

Comment: Okay, did you by chance put up a Joomla site, register the domain with Google webmaster and leave it for a while? Seems like Google has picked up and cached content from the site which is outdated. If I take a google page preview the pop-up text (in the yellow box) looks fine. I don't think you have anything to worry about. Just give it some time, let google re-index it and things will be fine. Register a sitemap if you haven't already and give it a week. The text showing up is nowhere on the site so should go away when the pages are re-indexed. Things look better in Google+ though.

Comment: Thanx ali, will wait for a week and see how things happen

Answer (score 0):

Your home website not show metadescription and keyword although you config it in Global Configuration .

Menu manager -->Home is Front Page Blog view.Try insert metadesc and keyword in file

I try using get values from configuration.php.But it not working with 2 parameter MetaDesc, MetaKeys.

Edit file yourwebsite\components\com_content\views\frontpage\view.html.php

$config = & JFactory::getConfig();

$document->setDescription($config->getValue( 'config.MetaDesc'));

Sumary I fix my problem like that,
Edit file yourwebsite\components\com_content\views\frontpage\view.html.php

**$document->setMetadata(“keyword abc here”);**

**$document->setDescription( "Description about your website" );**

Hope this help someone have some problem's.My name is vanhien771354

www.nhipcau.us