# Facebook like not extracting right image from meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I can't seem to get Facebook's like functionality to use the image I supply with the og:image meta tag.

Instead it uses some random picture on my site.

Check out this article:
http://www.tacky.nl/skateboard/article/?id=109170

If I check the page with facebook's [url linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tacky.nl%2Fskateboard%2Farticle%2F%3Fid%3D109170) it extracts the correct image (and data), but when I use the share button to share the page, then it uses another image. Any ideas why?

I have added what I assume is the right xmlns, all the required meta tags and the facebook javascript sdk init at the end of the page. Any help is appreciated. I use FBML, not iframe.

Comment: It seems it work correctly now, tbh I dunno what fixed it, maybe it takes some time before facebook recognizes that you have og:/fb: tags and have stored that you don't so it does a different selection instead?

Comment: I just ran into this.  My testing shows that Facebook caches outbound requests in their proxy system including 404 responses. Meaning if you have a <og:image tag that links to an image that doesn't exist then add the image back the image won't show up until the Facebook cache expires.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is that the image you're seeing was actually cached from an earlier attempt to Like the page before the og additions?

Comment: Was afraid of that as well, but have tried completely new articles as well that have never been shared before. It's for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this tag as well, wouldn't hurt:

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.tacky.no/m/201009/272045.jpg" />
```

Comment: Tried it now and it didn't work.