# og:image won't show up in my Facebook feed, when I like stuff at my site

Tags: facebook, xfbml, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Ok, I just launched a site: http://www.haavekuva.fi/ yesterday and on that site I've implemented Facebook's social plugin "fb:like", so it's possible to like a photo.

Everything else works fine ("Like" gets published to my feed with correct title, link, etc.), but for some reason the og:image does not show up? When I hover over the the"Like"-link ("Janne likes Shopping on Haavekuva.") on my profile feed, on the hover-box it shows only Facebook question mark.

If I linter the page at developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.haavekuva.fi%2Fkalenteri%2Fpaiva%2F2010-10-10%2Fshopping%2F there the photo is correctly visible.

Does anyone have any idea why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No image will be represented within the stream when a user "Likes" something, unless they also add a comment (at the point of liking it). Not sure if that was the answer you were looking for, but hopefully it clears things up.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, my liked url are getting the right image show up.

Answer (score 6):

**Are your images the right size and ratio?** 
They have a limit of at least 50x50 pixels in size and at max an aspect ratio of 3:1.

> og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph. The image must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. You may include multiple og:image tags to associate multiple images with your page.

Read more: [Facebook open graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

**It could be something else though...**
Until a couple of days ago, everything worked fine on my site http://ahrengot.com/. But now, for some inexplicable reason, the images won't show when pages are shared. I know facebook detects the images, because they show up in [The URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/). I have not changed anything in the code. This just came as a bug out of the blue.

*I think this might be a temporary bug on their part, but it sure is annoying.*

**Yes, the above was a temporary bug on Facebook's part. My images are included again whenever pages from http://ahrengot.com are shared on Facebook**