# Facebook Like Meta Tags not showing Images

Tags: image, facebook, cakephp, facebook-like, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I have implemented the Facebook Like button on all our pages and it works properly by posting to Facebook with the correct meta tags.  However, the images do not show in Facebook.  The image meta tags show up properly when I use the Facebook Linter, but they don't show on someone's facebook page where the Like is posted on their wall.  Also, is there any way to have the info recache more often? The tags take forever to update. Our site is built with CakePHP. Below are snippets of my code, thanks:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head> 
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/wlx8xgm.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    <?php 
    if(!isset($meta_title)) {
        $meta_title = $title_for_layout;
    }
    if(!isset($meta_location)) {
        $meta_location = null;
    }
    if(!isset($meta_image)) {
        $meta_image = null;
    }
    if(!isset($meta_type)) {
        $meta_type = null;
    }
    ?>

    <meta property="og:title" content="<?= $meta_title ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="<?= $meta_type ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?= $meta_location ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?= $meta_image ?>"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1004432800"/>
```

...

```
echo '<br><br><fb:like href="' . $fbook_url . '" width="300" height="80" layout="standard" show_faces="true" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what type of URL are you using? relative or absolute?
Also, if it's a cache problem then just use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $meta_image . '?' . rand(); ?>"/>
```

EDIT: You should use the `like` script from the like plugin [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).

Comment: What's showing in the page is below (this link actually works):
<meta property="og:image" content="www.caroverload.com/dev_overload/img/garage_car/gc2_i3.jpg">
does it need an http://??

Comment: is this image really exists? because I can't access it? do you have any special code in your `.htaccess`?also adding my code to it will add `....jpg?4234` [read this](http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=275), if this solves the problem then it's a cache problem

Comment: actaully sorry. posted wrong link... this is from another page on my website with an image path that definitely works:
<meta property="og:image" content="www.caroverload.com/dev_overload/img/car/c1288_i902.jpg">

Comment: ok so have you added the random function? also can you post an actual link for a page that has this issue? what happens if you try putting a smaller image (thumbnail that is >= 50x50 pixels)?

Comment: is there a size limit on the images?  they are pretty big.  I can use the thumbnails instead but i gotta code it and see what happens.  will keep you updated. i really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: No Im just guessing here, maybe (for some reason) facebook is failing of processing your image and creating a thumbnail for it...once again, have you tried adding the `rand()` function?

Comment: Check out this image:
https://skitch.com/hahmadi82/r8t7j/caroverload-testuser
There was no problem with the images loading, as you can see in the "likes" section in lower left. However, they still don't show in the posts (on the wall).  Is there some flag I need to set for that?  My old code was actually working for the images. It's very important that the wall posts show the image too since this is a viral aspect of our website. I was playing with loading in smaller images until I noticed those images in the like section from the older cached version.

Comment: just tried rand function. didn't change anything

Comment: You've just said your old code was working...but just checking your like script here...this is not the latest! can you get the latest from the like plugin [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) and post the result?

Comment: the code i posted above is the latest. what is different? i'm using the XFBML example

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that you use both the `href` and the `url` meta tag which is not necessary. Anyway, I can't think of anything else...one last try would be use the `rand()` function on the url and href and check if anything is changed