# Facebook Like Button: specify graphic for this page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm using the Facebook "like" button with the Javascript API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

When someone clicks "like" and adds a comment, Facebook posts it to their wall with a little thumbnail graphic. That graphic appears to be specified in the OpenGraph meta tags that I had to add to the site (which are detailed near the bottom of the page I linked to above -- see og:url). And that graphic appears to be site-wide for my domain.

My question: instead of having one general graphic for all my "liked" pages on my site, can I specify a graphic for each individual page, that will be carried over to Facebook when the user "like"s that page?

Thanks-- E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course, just remember the graphic you want to share should go in the `og:image` meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"/>
```

Just make sure you satisfy the conditions:

> og:image - The URL to an image that
>   represents the entity. Images must be
>   at least 50 pixels by 50 pixels.
>   Square images work best, but you are
>   allowed to use images up to three
>   times as wide as they are tall.

Comment: I have that image tag already in the header since it's part of the OpenGraph meta info for the site. Are you suggesting that I override that for each page of my site? I'll try it, though it seems to fly in the face of the "spirit" of having these og: tags on every page.

Comment: @Eric: If you want different images on different pages then yes, you need different image meta..at the end this is what the meta tags are for!