# Facebook share link - can you customize the message body text?

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a link that will share a page on Facebook.  So far I've got:

```
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php
?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F
&t=CNN%26s+website"
```

However, I'd really like to add some text that will go in the *'What's on your mind?'* text box (especially as the `t` value gets overridden by the link's title).  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: [@Ardee_Aram's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799060/3307368) answer is still working for people wondering.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You **can't** do this using sharer.php, **but** you can do something similar using the Dialog API. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?  
app_id=123050457758183&  
link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&  
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&  
caption=Reference%20Documentation& 
description=Dialogs%20provide%20a%20simple,%20consistent%20interface%20for%20applications%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

[image: Facebook dialog example]

The catch is you must create a dummy Facebook application just to have an `app_id`. Note that your Facebook application doesn't have to do ANYTHING at all. Just be sure that it is properly configured, and you should be all set.

### November 2021 update

The feed part of the `Dialog API` no longer includes the `message` field in the message. It is not included in the [feed dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog). The fields `picture`, `name`, `caption`, and `description` are now deprecated.

Therefore, for the purpose of sharing to the wall, you're better off with `sharer.php`, which does **not** require an `app_id`, and therefore does not need registering an app:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://example.com
```

Comment: Is this still working? Cause when I go to your url, the message is not set.

Comment: I haven't tried again, but judging how the Facebook API changes, I won't be surprised that it's not working anymore.

Comment: No longer feasible in any way. See their [Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control)

Comment: This don't work if you indend to share a google play link, because both the summary and title will not appear in the shared post.

Answer (score 56):

**NOTE:** @azure_ardee solution is no longer feasible. Facebook will not allow developers pre-fill messages. Developers may customize the story by providing OG meta tags, but it's up to the user to fill the message.

This is only possible if you are posting on the user's behalf, which requires the user authorizing your application with the [`publish_actions` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). **AND** even then:

> please note that Facebook recommends using a user-initiated sharing modal.

---

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem/4977967#4977967).

Comment: Yeah, the Facebook API just changes a freaking lot ;) It's really hard to keep up.

Answer (score 12):

Like @Ardee said you sharer.php uses data from the meta tags, the Dialog API accepts parameters. Facebook have removed the ability to use the message parameter but you can use the quote parameter which can be useful in a lot of cases e.g.

[image]

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
app_id=[your-app-id]
&display=popup
&title=This+is+the+title+parameter
&description=This+is+the+description+parameter
&quote=This+is+the+quote+parameter
&caption=This+is+the+caption+parameter
&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.[url-in-your-accepted-list].com
```

Just have to create an app id:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Then make sure the redirect url domain is listed in the accepted domains for that app.

Answer (score 5):

To add some text, what I did some time ago , if the link you are sharing its a page you can modify. You can add some meta-tags to the shared page:

```
<meta name="title" content="The title you want" />
<meta name="description" content="The text you want to insert " />
<link rel="image_src" href="A thumbnail you can show" / >
```

It's a small hack. Although the old share button has been replaced by the "like"/"recommend" button  where you can add a comment if you use the XFBML version. More info her:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 5):

Like said in [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#configurator), use

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
```

image size recommended: 1 200 x 630

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not allow you to change the "What's on your mind?" text box, unless of course you're developing an application for use on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in the Dialog API, which triggers starting a message on Messenger. (Note: this is different from "posting to your wall" in the accepted answer, the difference being `/dialog/send` instead of `/dialog/feed`).

For example:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?  
app_id=123050457758183&  
link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

See [the Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog). As of November 2021, the documentation does not show the fields `picture`, `name`, `caption`, `description`: they are populated from the Open Graph tags of the website. I tried adding the field `message` and it failed to produce any text, but the link still redirects to Messenger.