# Add value to textarea in child window

Tags: php, jquery

I have a remote url that is opening with window.open(url), in that page there is a textarea, i want to change the value of that textarea from my parent page.

```
window.open("http://facebook.com/share.php?u=
                http://something.com&t="+txt,'facebook','height=400,width=550'); 

$("textarea#u_0_6").val('test');
```

thank you

Comment: This is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023602/facebook-share-body-text see @ifaour:s answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it like this. method is very simple, you can transfer your value with hash (#) like that;

```
window.open("http://facebook.com/share.php?u=
                http://something.com&t="+txt+"#this is my textarea value",'facebook','height=400,width=550'); 

 $(function() {
   var MyTextAreaValue = window.location.hash;
   $('#u_0_6').val(MyTextAreaValue);
 });
```

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't saw facebook link.