# Simple facebook user feed on rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I've searched through a lot of posts and haven't found exactly what I was looking for. Just curious if there was a relatively simple way to post the status updates of one business page to a rails site.

I don't need it to do anything fancy, just list the last several statuses from a single profile.

Is there a gem for that?

Thanks.

Comment: looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023602/facebook-share-body-text