# facebook Messager URL with predefined message

Tags: facebook, messenger

All I'm looking to do is invoke a chat with a predefined message.  The following URL does exactly what I'm looking for but it does not appear I can pass in a predefined message.  Is there?

```
https://m.me.com/<USER_ID>
```

Is there a different URL or API that I can use to invoke a FB message?

Comment: message prefilling is not allowed anyway, so what is the point?

Comment: FB doesn't allow message prefilling through the URL?? Or not at all through any of their API's?  What'sApp allows you to with a simple URL like this:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567&text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale

This is what I was hoping to do as well with FB Messager

Comment: you need to read the platform policy. it´s not allowed in general.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comments to this effect, [Facebook's developer guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/policy#messengerplatform) under the sub-heading **2. Give people control** explicitly disallow pre-filling of content:

> Don’t prefill any content in captions, comments, messages or the user message parameter of posts unless (a) it is a single hashtag in a post shared through our Share Dialog (but not via our APIs), (b) it was created by the person using your app, or (c) it was created by a business whose employees use your app to administer the business’s presence on Facebook.

In the case that you do satisfy one of the above conditions, I believe the solution may be to use a [m.me link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links), although I am not at all certain how to go about crafting the `USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD` in a useful manner.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023602/facebook-share-link-can-you-customize-the-message-body-text) may provide more useful information for the specifics of implementation, but the consensus in answers is that even in the 3 cases where it is allowed to pre-fill, such a model is explicitly discouraged by Facebook.  (This likely explains why they do not appear to document how to do this, and few if any good answers exist online).

Comment: Well it actually says you can under curtain conditions.  In the case (b) this is exactly purpose of what we are trying to accomplish.  So in this case is there a parameter to pass in?

Comment: Good point, I feel silly for not noticing that.  I'll take a look.