# Facebook Share Button with Prefilled input text is available?

Tags: facebook, button, input, text, share

I am using reactjs.

I want to add a string in to the share popup's input field, but I had no success.

Is this option available yet?

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799060/1207049

Comment: @markful: that answer is from 2011, and very outdated.

Comment: The simply share button does not allow for any such thing AFAIK; but the Share _Dialog_ has options to provide a hashtag, and even an additional “quote suggestion” (the user will be able to remove that again, if they don’t like it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefilling the text is not possible and (even more important) not allowed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: thanks
and can I give a hashtag to the input field?
I remember something like that, but I don't know who can I add it, or it is possible yet.

Comment: no, of course not. it has to be 100% user generated.