# How do I change the facebook recommended text, link or thumbnail image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When a user recommends my link (which has content, images, etc) it only displays the site name as the link with no text or images. How can I edit it so it does so?

My code is as follows;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appID=1234567890&xfbml=1"></script> 

   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        //replace the next line with calling your div
        alert('Shared!');
   });
 </script>
 <fb:like href="http://www.mysite.com/" send="false" width="450" show_faces="true" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Add open graph meta tags to your page so it knows what to pull in.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

On http://www.mysite.com/, add the `og:image` meta tag for an image and `og:description` to customize the text.

Docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

There's a linter tool that checks whether you did it right:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug