# How to Update a Facebook Like button

Tags: iframe, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)
>   [How to clear Facebook Sharer cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256114/how-to-clear-facebook-sharer-cache)

I placed a Facebook Like button on my website about 7 days ago. It seemed to work fine; except several days later I noticed that it was giving out the wrong meta data in the Facebook message that is sent. The  Title, the Description and the Canonical URL were all wrong. Mea Culpa. It was my fault. I had cloned an old page to save time, had changed the content but had forgotten to change the Meta data at the top.  Easy to fix, right. Edit the html page. WRONG. Made no difference. Deleted the Like button code, and re-created a new Like button on the Facebook Developers website and pasted the new code. Made no difference. The button still shows the Meta data from the first button.Tried different variations of button code. Made no difference whatever. It seems the original data has been cached in the Facebook database, and cannot be changed. 
Any help somebody?

Answer (score 0):

Load the URL in the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). That might flush the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try changing URL with a query string in the end.
Also, URL Linter provides you an insight on how FB is going to read your like Meta Tags.
it is always a good practice to check your like page URL here and see what all Meta Tags FB is picking up ..
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug