# When sharing a page you made on facebook I get one thumbnail?

Tags: facebook, request, hyperlink, sharing, thumbnails

I've been sharing my pages alot, but all I get is one thumbnail. I see this: 1 of 1 (“Choose a Thumbnail”). Please show me how to put more on that on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another thumbnail by adding the following to the `<head>` section of your site.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/link/to/you/image.jpg"/>
```

see [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)

It's worth noting that Facebook does cache a list of images from a url so you have to wait for this to take affect. Or link to another page.