# Facebook is not showing Thumbnail Image on share page

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook-sharer, video-thumbnails

I am trying to share my video on facebook, it is sharing fine but video thumbnail is not showing on the share page.

my code is :

```
window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=" + inv_getlocation() + "&p[title]=" + shareTitle + "&p[summary]="+ shareDesc + "&p[images][0]=" + shareThumb);
```

If anyone have any idea about this, please share.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem : You can go through this link to find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some chnages in my images, which I'm using for thumbnail image, now some posts shows thumbs and some doesn't show any thumb, if someone faced this type of problem please share.

You can go through [this link](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200310786187595&added&referer=new_question) for more information.