# Facebook Open Graph Displays image even though "Picture" parameter not sent

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

In PHP I make the following call - note I do not have the "picture" parameter in the call so I assume that no image will appear with the post on the pages wall. However Facebook seems to go and grab a random image from the site which the URL is sent in the call. Any ideas how to stop FB doing this?

`access_token=[access token is here]&message=Income Generator Earned 100 Pips While Sleeping!&link=http://bit.ly/eFdKin&name=Click here to read more...&caption=MarksInvestingBlog&description=What I do know is that the Knowledge to Action strategies work` - however! You need to practice, practice and practice more until you get a "feel" for the currency pairs you are trading. I also tr...&source=

Answer (score 0):

You can place this meta tag into your target URL:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="#" />
```

This way it will not display any image. It can be changed also at URL parameters, but I don't have any sample code at hand to show in this computer.

Comment: So it the web page was on a blog this would be in the meta head section?

Comment: Yes, that tag specifies the image that is displayed in the wall story and goes into the HEAD, the sooner the better. Btw, if you want to show an image, it as to be in a absolute URL into href or it won't work.

Comment: This looks good http://riajournal.com/ria/index.php/2009/06/01/customizing-what-gets-shown-in-facebook-when-a-user-shares-your-page/

Comment: If it helped mark the question as solved by clicking on the symbol! For every question not resolved god kills a kitten :(