# facebook share button with custom title, description, and image

Tags: facebook, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

It looks like that the Facebook support custom title, description, and thumbnail in several ways.

So far, I have found two solutions.

1. using meta tag

   ```
   [meta name="title" content="title" /]
   [meta name="description" content="description" /]
   ```
2. using URL parameters.

   ```
   [a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=WEB1CHANNEL&p[summary]=Web+Design+Company+in+Dubai.&p[url]=http://www.webchannel.ae&p[images][0]=http://qacode.com/test.jpg']asdfa[/a]
   ```

I really like solution #2, but it looks like it is not stable. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Overall, it works anyway.

Is it okay to use solution #2? Is it going to be available in the future?

Answer (score 10):

1. Use [Open-Graph Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to let Facebook get the data you want when scraping the page.
2. Facebook will not respect the parameters you pass to `sharer.php` instead it'll try to get the info from the page.
3. The [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is the way to go and if you really don't have a good reason to use sharer...don't use it!
4. Check your URL against the [Facebook Debbuger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to better test your links.

Comment: With Meta Tags, you cannot share a custom image

Answer (score 0):

As for as I have seen solution number 2 is not stable. I have seen many problems related to solution 2 in facebook as well as in this forum too. I have personally experienced that it is better to use meta tags with xfbml version of fb:share.

```
<fb:share-button type="button_count" href="http://<?php echo($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>"></fb:share-button>
```

It doesn't stop working in my experience.