# Facebook will not display the image from my page as a thumbnail, when posting it on my status

Tags: php, facebook, share, facebook-sharer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

On one of my sites I want the users to be able to share a page and with that attach the page image as thumbnail on facebook. If I use my “Share” button which I have on my Google Toolbar in my browser, it displays the headline, some of the text and my image – everything looks just alright.

But, if I copy the URL and put it into my Status field on facebook, it only displays the title and my h1 headline but no picture. So almost identical, except the missing picture.

I’m not enough familiar with the facebook way to “extract” images on when coping an URL into the Status field but it strikes me as weird that the “shared” pop-up page works fine and not the other.

Can it have something to do how I reference the image in my code? As it is now, the picture are displayed with this link `<img src="/uploads/sqrecipe/54/312_530x400_d99dcd230.jpeg" alt="312_530x400_d99dcd230" />`

There is some other images as well on the page, but which is not the, like “post image” and they are referenced the same way as the above post image.

Hope some of you can sheet some light on this issue. Any hints og solutions would be very much appreciated.

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `meta` tag to inform Facebook of the image you want to share as thumbnail. Use this code below in your `<head>` section

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yourwebsite.com/uploads/sqrecipe/54/312_530x400_d99dcd230.jpeg" />
```

**Note:** you have to specify the absolute URL for the image, including your domain name. You can read more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Answer (score 0):

Also, the page may be cached by fb servers, you can refresh the fb cache using the Lint tool found here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/