# Facebook image sharing problem

Tags: php, javascript, css, facebook, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I have a website named as IdiotsTube , on it I embed videos from youtube. Whenever some one share the link of some video page on facebook. It looks for an image, how can I add a custom image to it.

Like can I hide image somewhere in the page or can add one some where on meta then facebook also crawls that image.

Basically the problem I am facing is that the images crawled by the facebook are irrelivant

Like if someone share this page :
[Wake Up Muslim](http://www.idiotstube.com/video.php?url=2kOkEstB3s4)

Then the images crawled by facebook are not the images which I want.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting some metas. Read more here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

e.g.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```