# Using Facebook's Open Graph protocol, are multiple thumbnail images allowed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

According to Facebook's [Open Graph protocol documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), you may include multiple `og:image` meta properties to associate multiple images with your page:

> `og:image` - An image URL which should
>   represent your object within the
>   graph. The image must be at least 50px
>   by 50px and have a maximum aspect
>   ratio of 3:1. We support PNG, JPEG and
>   GIF formats. You may include multiple
>   `og:image` tags to associate multiple
>   images with your page.

However, when I load my page in the [URL Linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint), I get a warning:

> Duplicate tags:   You used "image" multiple times, but it should only appear once

So which is it?

Is there a better way to associate multiple thumbnail images with a page?

Comment: It's just their Linter... as you said, multiple og:image works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

You can add multiple og:image meta tags. facebook has left/right arrow controls that allow the user to choose between the images.

If URL Linter sees more than one og:image tag, it should show under the Debug as a Data Source with multiple values:

> Extracted 3 values from `<meta property="og:image" />`: [image
>   location], [image location], [image location]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the og:image meta tag, you can add your thumbnail images to the end of the DOM and set their visibility to hidden.  The thumbnails will be recognized by Facebook even though they are not visible on the page itself.  I usually do this as an added precaution just because I have experienced some flaky behavior with the meta tags in the past.

Comment: This sounds very promising. Will you please edit your answer to include an example?

Comment: If you set an ```og:image``` tag, Facebook doesn't read other images at DOM. So you must consider one: to use opengraph and set images manually or facebook takes data from DOM automatically.