# Control the image that facebook shows when I like a URL

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

As the owner of the page being liked, is there anyway to control the url that shows up on the wall of people who like my page?

[image]

See the above image? Like a blog post on this page: www.sunlitehardware.com.au and you will note that the "thrifty link" logo, found in the bottom right hand corner of the website, is displayed (as shown in the picture above). I want to change that to a sunlite hardware logo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the meta tag to tell which image to show on your post to your wall:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="(your image link)"/>
```

Related Articles:

http://bobbelderbos.com/2011/03/facebook-like-button-right-image/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/