# image-tags for google or facebook

Tags: image, facebook, tags, blogs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

i have a blog with some images on it. now i want a specific one to appear on  pages like google+ or facebook.
when i click on "+1" it shows a facebook-image, but not the image of the actual blog-entry. its the same with facebook :(

do i have to give the image a special tag or so?

```
name="blog-name" title="blog-name" alt="blog-name" ?
```

example:

```
<img src="/TwitterIcon.png" title="Blogname auf Twitter" width="22px" border="0">
```

works

```
<img src="/m/home_button.png" title="Blogname" width="50px" border="0">
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the tags on the images, use the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) protocol.  Let Facebook scrape via Open Graph-friendly meta tags:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

This will result in Facebook grabbing http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg.