# Facebook same meta tags worked on one host and not worked on another

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I use facebook debugger for test my page (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).
When I test this page  - http://chatterbay-test.appspot.com/user/FlashMaster, debugger can't find any meta tags, but when I try test same code on another server - http://194.105.145.52:8080/wc/face.html debugger show title, description and image.

Answer (score 1):

That's because if you go to http://chatterbay-test.appspot.com/user/FlashMaster you need to sign in.

As such the debug tool can't read your page.

Comment: And the sign in page lacks those meta tags. +1.