# Facebook sharer won't embed image in IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-sharer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm trying to share a video from feralmotion.com using

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>
```

The page I'm trying to share [can be viewed here](http://www.feralmotion.com?watch=1925)

It may be important to mention [I am sharing flowplayer](http://www.facebook.com/flowplayer?v=app_7146470109)

I can properly share video's to webkit and -moz- browsers, but when 
  I share on IE, the image never makes it to Facebook.  This leaves facebooks tiny play button neatly tucked in the top left corner, in a not-so-obvious fashion.

[Test it for yourself here, try in different browsers.](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.feralmotion.com/share?watch=1925)

It may be important to mention that the facebook linter finds the image when

```
http://www.feralmotion.com/share?watch=1925
```

is run through it.

Has anyone come across this before ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [Open Graph Meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to your page: `/?watch=XXX`

These meta tags are added to your "share" pages: `/share?watch=XXX` and there's no reason **not** to add them to your actual pages!

---

**EDIT:**
Based on the comments below, it seems that it's a bug in the `sharer.php` script.
P.S: The [Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is recommended over the `sharer.php`

Comment: This page is an example I set up with flowplayer: http://sdoyle.fbdublin.com/tests/tasks/632942.html , when you share that URL on Facebook it creates a feed story with the video player embedded

Comment: sorry. . . maybe I'm missing your point. . . all of the open graph tags are there. . . and it works like a charm across all browsers except IE... where the video is still embedded/just the image doesn't make it across to fb.

Comment: Oh sorry about that! it seems that it's a problem with the `sharer.php` script, because if you share the link on Facebook directly using IE or using the Like plugin it will work just fine. I'm not sure if Facebook is still supporting the `sharer.php` though! @Igy please confirm?

Comment: @Igy btw, +1 for the secret FB domain :-), I didn't know that you like turtles ;-)

Comment: If it's a reproducible bug in sharer.php, please report it and we'll triage it as normal, we no longer recommend use of sharer.php but it hasn't been complete deprecated yet either, so it should be fixed

Comment: reported it - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20033

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. The bug-report link in the comment before me is a dead link as of now... :\