# Facebook "Send" button picture not showing

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Favebook Send social button image is not showing,

it is showing a picture for when an image is not found.

When I do look at the "Frame" source I notice that the URL for the 
image is valid.

Could this be caching problem, since I have set the meta tag property
to show to a new Picture yet the old url of the image is showing

Need help please...

Comment: provide sample of problem (live url or jsfiddle.net use case)

Comment: Please note the Like and Send at the bottom of the Page is misbehaving
http://apps.facebook.com/wayne_beachwatch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I view your [source code](http://view.beachwatch.co.za:8080/BeachWatchVideoServer/Category.jsp) I see an og:image tag pointing to this image: http://apps.facebook.com/wayne_beachwatch/images/bw_32X32.png

However, if you go to this image, its not actually an image and loads up a full Facebook branded page.  Point that image meta tag to a real image on your beachwatch.co.za server, like:
http://view.beachwatch.co.za:8080/BeachWatchVideoServer/images/bw_32X32.png
[image: http://view.beachwatch.co.za:8080/BeachWatchVideoServer/images/bw_32X32.png]