# facebook won't show my oh:image thumbnails no matter what I do

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Ok guys.. I've researched this thoroughly- I'm at the end of my rope and my supervisor is getting pissed. Any help is appreciated.

[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) [opengraph](/questions/tagged/opengraph) thumbnails do not work when I share pages from my site.  I'm sure I have og:image implemented correctly. I have resized the JPG thumbnails to 130x110 pixels. I have even tried hiding another copy of the same thumbnails in the pages with display:none.

example page: http://www.classical917.org/houston_public_radio-arte_publico.php

from that page:

The Facebook debugger (formerly the Linter) picks up the URL of the image, but displays a blank box. When I click on the blank box, the image loads.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.classical917.org%2Fhouston_public_radio-arte_publico.php

When I post a page from my site into a Facebook 'What's on Your Mind?' box, Facebook gets the title and description from my og: tags, thinks for a while about the image, then loads with no image.

Is it because I'm trying to use the same logo image for every page on the site? Is that a no-no? Is there something wrong with my image (although I've tried several versions)? Am I being penalized for using the debugger too often? Does Facebook hate my site?

Thanks for any ideas or pointers on this. I'm desperate to fix it before I get called into my supervisor's office.. : P

Answer (score 0):

Your site has 215 xhtml validation errors according to the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.classical917.org/houston_public_radio-arte_publico.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Facebook may be having a hard time parsing your page with so many errors.  It could also be a caching issue, although the linter tool should clean up the cache, and the linter tool is pulling in the image properly. It may also not like full path URL's. Try a relative path.

As a work-around, you could also try specifying an image the old way:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/_images/logo-facebook-130x110-kuha.jpg" />
```

The rest of your questions are invalid (Facebook isn't penalizing you and they don't care if you are using the same image).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing line break in the `og:description` meta.