# Like button results in odd image on wall post

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I've added a "like" button to my website and it works perfectly, except for the image that Facebook chooses to pull for the thumbnail on the resulting wall post. When someone clicks on the "like" button, the wall post features the logo of one of our sponsors rather than our logo.

Is there a way to specify which image facebook takes for wall posts when people click the "like" button?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add the open graph meta tags to your page. Then you can "instruct" the Like button what to use rather than having it guess.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://site.com/you_image.jpg" />
```

You should add all the suggested "og" meta tags (title, url, site name, etc)