# How to tell Facebook what images to offer a user when posting a link to my web page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

When a user posts a link to my webpage to share on Facebook, Facebook scans my webpage/site and offers up some images found in that page. The user selects one to associate with the fb post.

Can I control which images on my web page facebook will offer up to the user to use in a post?

A feature that looks close is Open Graph Tags, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ , but it doesn't seem to suffice my particular need as it seems to allow just one image to represent that page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by generating a "super proxy" this will create based on dynamic information your application provides the meta data needed by facebook sharer, you can check this working on this link: http://concursos.genommalab.com/soyflaca/ I made this website and since all the content comes from a single page to share every one of the items has a customize one I used a deep link technique and send it to my super proxy that generated the static content to the facebook sharer.php, here is the code:

```
<?php
    // get our URL query parameters
    $current_path = 'http://' . dirname($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $title = $_GET['t'];
    $diet_id = $_GET['diet_id'];
    $desciption = $_GET['desc'];
    $image_thumb = $_GET['thumb'];
    $shared_url = $_GET['surl'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="title" content="<?php echo $title;?>" />
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $desciption;?>" />
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=<?php echo $current_path . '/#diet_' . $diet_id; ?>" />
  <link rel="<?php echo $image_thumb; ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<img src="<?php echo $image_thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo 'Imagen de ' . $title; ?>" width="112" height="112" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Or perhaps all you want to do is add a list of images available to facebook, like this...

```
<link rel="images/example_1.jpg" />
<link rel="images/example_2.jpg" />
<link rel="images/example_3.jpg" />
<link rel="images/example_4.jpg" />
<link rel="images/example_5.jpg" />
```

Right inside `<head> </head>` tags. Remember this are scanned by facebook sharer.php