# Problem defining og:image path for php-generated Open Graph meta tags - product images don't display when Facebook Like button is clicked

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm trying to define the correct path for product images within my site's Open Graph meta tags so when someone clicks the embedded Like or Send button, an image from the specific product page they're on will display in Facebook.

My website is running on a bespoke php-based e-commerce solution. Its head section is entirely generated in php, making it extra difficult (for me) to write the Open Graph meta tags.

The code I have so far is:

```
echo("\t<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"{$config["absolute_url"]}/media/productimages/{$data["imageid"]}/{$data["extension"]}\" />\n");
```

... which just displays a blank image in Facebook's developer linter, and no image at all when Like or Send buttons are clicked on my website.

I've tried lots of (rubbish) solutions but nothing works - I'm new to php and struggling big-time! The developer who built our site is not available to help me, and moving to another e-commerce cart isn't financially viable at present, so I'm up sh!t creek sans paddle with this one.

Any help, tips or advice would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

Thanks! =]

---

Added 13/09/11:

In case it helps, here's the whole chunk of OG meta tags from my site's head section:

```
// Output Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags
    echo("\t<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"".page_title()."\" />\n");
    echo("\t<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"article\" />\n");
    echo("\t<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"ElectricPlanet.co.uk\" />\n");
    echo("\t<meta property=\"fb:app_id\" content=\"135246374547713\" />\n");
    echo("\t<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"{$config["absolute_url"]}/media/productimages/{$data["imageid"]}.{$data["extension"]}\" />\n");
    echo("\t<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"{$config["absolute_url"]}".seo_url_encode($productdata['title'])."\" />\n");
```

All the other OG tags are working fine, except for the og:url one, which I'm also currently flummoxed by. =S

Here's a snippet from where images are output:

```
echo("<img src=\"{$config["absolute_url"]}/media/productimages/{$data["imageid"]}_product.{$data["extension"]}\" height=\"{$config["product_image_height"]}\" width=\"{$config["product_image_width"]}\" id=\"mainProductImage\" alt=\"{$productdata["title"]}\" />");
```

And here's a link to a typical product page:

http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/product/26/211/Mathmos-Astrobaby-Lava-Lamp

Big kudos to anyone who takes a look at this for me - I'm extremely grateful, even if we don't crack this issue. I've never actually asked for coding help before - my MO is to 'trial-and-error' stressfully for about ten days until I either solve something or throw my 'puter against a wall! - but while I've managed to self-teach myself to an ok level in html, css and a little javascript, I'm completely out of my depth when it comes to php.

So thanks again in advance, Stack Overflow gurus!

Cheers, Ross

Comment: Is the generated image url correct? Can you please give us the link to one of the pages, that would help a lot.

Comment: Hi Arjuna, thanks for replying. I think the generated image url is correct - product images display properly throughout the site. Here's a link to a product page: [http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/product/519/Lace-Lights---LED-Shoe-Laces](http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/product/519/Lace-Lights---LED-Shoe-Laces) - thanks again for looking at this for me. =]

Comment: Any more ideas? This is driving me insane... =[  Thanks!

Comment: Your code is not generating the correct urls, if you check the source of http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/product/519/Lace-Lights---LED-Shoe-Laces (View -> Page Source) you'll see the og tags  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/media/productimages/_product." />
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/product// " />
that are clearly broken. Fixing that should solve your problems, also remember to use the Linter to check your OG implementation https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes, thanks anyway Arjuna, but I already realise my code isn't generating the correct urls, and I know precisely where it's wrong - that's manifest in my question, I think. It's actually why it's wrong and HOW to fix the code to generate the correct urls that I need help with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be not slash, but dot must be here?
 {$data["imageid"]}/{$data["extension"]}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Anton. I changed the slash to a dot, as suggested. But Facebook still isn't picking up the php part of the image url. The linter just returns: `Extracted 1 values from <meta property="og:image" />: http://www.electricplanet.co.uk/media/productimages/.` and no images display yet...

Comment: Any more ideas? This is driving me insane... =[  Thanks!