# Providing a set of images to use as thumbnail when sharing a URL

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm aware that you can specify a particular thumbnail on any given page by using the og:image meta property. The caveat with this technique is that it doesn't allow a user sharing the URL a reasonable method of changing the thumbnail should other images show on that page. (If this is incorrect, please let me know.)

Is there a way to specify a default thumbnail image but at the same time not alienate the other potential thumbnails that could have been grabbed?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple open graph image tags and it will let them choose, using the first one listed as the default.

Comment: This is heading in the right direction. The problem is I still have to explicitly add these tags in my header, and some pages (which are managed by a CMS) can have a variable number of images on them. So if I have an article page with a image associated with it, I'd like that to be an option as a thumbnail and have it only be a part of the page body. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You would have to add code to your CMS to look for images in the article and render them as meta tags.  Or get rid of all meta image tags and let the Facebook scraper choose the photo options.