# how to set the height and width for 'picture' property of a post in the Facebook Feed Dialog?

Tags: facebook, image, post, resize

When I try to post a link by share, the image that appears in the post along with the link needs to be resized. I need it bigger than the original preview image. Where and what parameters do I need to set?

I have found some meta tags for image. How to use them in Zend Php?

Answer (score 0):

Try to lookup this [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)
Describe about how to customize post with Facebook open-graph meta tags