# what graphic does FB grab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I am trying to figure out what photo Facebook grabs when you post a link.
It seems to be in consistent.

If you post this link into your status, it will grab a graphic in the middle of the page:

http://www.sfchamber.com/event_flash/2012.02.27/

If you post this link into your status, it will graph the top-graphic, which is preferable:

http://www.sfchamber.com/enews/current/

Any suggestions on how to grab the graphic of your choice?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

It will look for the [OpenGraph image tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).  In your `<head>`, you can specify this like:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.foo.com/myimage.jpg" />
```

For more information, check out the [OpenGraph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).  There's also a handy [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test how Facebook will see your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the specific og:image-tag! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ Scroll down to 'Open Graph Tags'.