# How do I get Facebook to show my site's logo when I paste the link in a post/status/comment?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

Facebook sometimes does this really neat thing where they show a thumbnail preview of a website you link to in a status update. It is usually the website's logo.

[image: fb status]

I'm wondering what the trick is to get this to work for my site, so if I were to share http://www.example.com, I would see my site's logo/favicon in that preview box. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try your site in this facebook debugger tool.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It will tell you what is missing.Eg. below in page head

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[url to image]" />
<meta property="og:title" content="[page name]" />
<meta property="og:description" content="[content description]" />
```

There are different ways depending on how your site is built. Eg. [This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-and-digg-thumbnail-generator/) Wordpress plugin creates a link for each image on the page so you can chose between your logo and any other post image on the page.

**Update 2017**: It is now recommended to [register a Facebook App ID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register) for your site otherwise the debugger will give you an error. [More tags and info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Comment: You saved the day with this debug! In my case my og:type wasn't the first one, then facebook aren't recognizing it.

Comment: I have done this and I still get this error message: "og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.oceanview335.com/Pictures/2015%20DDGMs.png' will be used instead."

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in your page's source:

`<link rel="image_src" href="http://somesite.org/img/title.jpg" />`