# How do I get Facebook to display my site's logo without cropping when typing in the URL?

Tags: ios, facebook, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

**I've followed the steps required for my client do exactly that, but somehow it's still not working.** [This is in reference to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864208/how-do-i-get-facebook-to-show-my-sites-logo-when-i-paste-the-link-in-a-post-sta/42467811#42467811)

I wrote the **Open graph code** in the head section and tested and **approved on Facebook debugger**. I even specified height and width in the og code.

```html
<meta property="og:title"  content="Kess Services Ltd|Construuction Works" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Flooring,roofing,ground works,scaffolding etc.All under one roof" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.kessservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/kess-logo-fb-jpg-200.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Whilst it works fine on everything I've tested, when my client typed www.kessservices.co.uk into her iPhone 6 on the Facebook app she sent me
[this screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Ucf.png)