# How do I change the image that is automatically posted on the wall after someone likes?

Tags: image, facebook-like, facebook-wall

If I have not put any open graph tags in my code. How does Facebook decide what image to post on the users wall after they have liked?

Answer (score 2):

It scrapes your page and looks for the images with certain dimensions and width/height ratio to choose from.
Have a look here:
[How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)