# Wrong image in facebook sharing - when using share intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I'm using next code to support sharing in my application:

```
//create the send intent  
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

//set the type  
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");  

//add a subject  
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject");  

String msg = https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.rovio.amazingalex.premium

//add the message  
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);  

//start the chooser for sharing  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sharing..."));
```

Even without any extra for image from my side,

facebook takes a random image, that is not part of my application, but kind of associate with it.

For example, when trying to share "Amazing Alex", this is the attached image:

[image]

How can I change this image?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Facebook tries to pull a thumbnail from the referenced URI. Perhaps the image was for an app on the left side of the page such as the column of "Users who viewed this also viewed
" ?

Comment: Yes, the image was for an app on the left side of the page such as the column of "Users who viewed this also viewed", How can I change it to my image?

Comment: Your answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images

Comment: This post is about sharing a page of my own. but when trying to share a link from google-play, I have only the link, and I can't change any detail in google play page...

Comment: David: Yes, I've also found that sharing a link to a Google Play app details page on Facebook results in only the link, with no image, unlike other links shared via Facebook.  I'm wondering if it is because Google Play apps compete with Facebook apps?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

String msg = https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.rovio.amazingalex.premium

You should use the following

String msg = https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:com.rovio.amazingalex.premium

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how to change the image, Facebook is using, but another solution could be to post a Link to your own webpage, where there is only a picture of your App, which Facebook will use in the post, and where you can define a redirect in the HTML Meta tags to your Google Play site.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.amazingalex.premium&feature=banner#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMSwiY29tLnJvdmlvLmFtYXppbmdhbGV4LnByZW1pdW0iXQ../">
</head>
```

So the tag above will redirect your visitor immediately to the page of google play. I justed tested it with a homepage of mine and Facebook is using the picture on it but the link redirects to google play. 
Be carefully: the page you are providing is shown shortly before the browser redirects.

Comment: nice patch, but I'm looking for a real solution. (In this way there is no image but not google play description neither)

Comment: nice ideea, I searched for another solution to but seems that is a facebook lack.

Comment: That kind of redirection might get your site in trouble with search engine spiders.  I don't know if they would penalize the entire site or just that one page - perhaps if you flagged the page as off-limits to spiders.  Facebook should be smart enough to detect it, in any case, so if they don't want content-full links to Google Play, they can probably find a way to prevent this...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook URL linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.jessechen.instawifi) to see what Facebook sees when they scrape the URL.  As you can see, my Android app also has the same issue where the picture is an app under the "Users who viewed this also viewed" section.

Unfortunately if you have to link directly to the Android Market, you can't change the image and as a consequence, there is no real solution to your problem unless Google decides to implement [OG tags](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags).  You can put in your own url (yours was not working when I tried it) into the URL linter to see how Facebook scrapes your link.

Comment: Funny thing - I was getting a naked link as my Facebook entry when a user tapped my sharing icon, *until* I ran the above Facebook URL linter on my URL.  That seems to have primed Facebook's pump with the images from my page (which the linter displays), because after running it just one time, I got an appropriate sharing icon in Facebook when I tapped on the sharing icon from my Nexus 7 tablet, and also from a friend's phone running 4.2.  Curious!

Comment: yep, if it was new then running the linter will force-scrape the page.  otherwise it takes some time for the fb scraper to come across your page.