# Facebook picking up an image from a page

Tags: html, facebook, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I'm curious as to why Facebook doesn't always pick up an image for a link that is posted when there are plenty of images on the page? I have several images but I cannot seem to get it to register one for it's link.

http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk

Is there anything I can do? Is it possible to create a particular image in my site that is hidden but Facebook will pick up on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OpenGraph Meta Tags](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags). Specifically, I  think you want the og:image one like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/klass/img/facebooklogo.png"/>
```

Comment: I've added this in but still not getting any image loading (not even the example one.) Could this be down to Facebook caching the link? I haven't posted it to the site yet but I have typed it in several times trying to get the whole thing to work.

Comment: Ya, Facebook will cache your URL. [Here are some techniques for busting the cache](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working fine after using the Facebook Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug