# Can we customize image and text returned by Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

When I pass URL to Facebook wall post, I get situation similar to this image

[image]

Is it possible to customize image (point 1) and text (point 2) returned by Facebook API?

In such case, a URL would still lead to www.google.com, but image and text would be custom ones.

I need to customize this as some images and text returned does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images) which explains how the page being shared can have meta tags which fill in these values

Comment: What if I do not own the site I publish link to? Can I attach my own images and text which will appear like on the image above?

Comment: nope, facebook uses the content provided by the site being linked to

Comment: thanks a lot. this was what I was looking for. I mean, I cannot do anything if I do not own the site linked to, but now I know it :).