# How to pass custom parameters to Facebook share link

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

How do I make a link that I can customize the title, image, link, and description that's shared?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### This no longer works as of 18/12/2013. See comments for alternatives.

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titleheresexily&p[url]=http://www.mysexyurl.com&p[summary]=mysexysummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://www.urltoyoursexyimage.com`

[image]

http://blog.cjgammon.com/?p=336

I was tired of scouring sites on google for this.

Comment: `<a id="facebookBtn" class="shareButton" data-desc="This is a description of the page" data-img="http://local/images/fbShare.jpg" data-url="http://local/" data-title="Title" target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0);">` with sharing like this, is it possible to customise the comment too?

Comment: Work partially: http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/fan.html

Comment: As of 18/12/2013, this no longer works. Any other ideas of using custom parameters?

Comment: works perfect!
but what is the strange `s=100` param?

Comment: sharer.php is deprecated now. The new way to do it is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @Ashish The Feed Dialog for web has been deprecated in API Version 2.0.
Facebook recomeds to use Share Dialog now,

Comment: FYI, the old Facebook share.php api is _**NO LONGER DEPRICATED**_ http://www.joshuawinn.com/facebooks-sharer-php-longer-deprecated-2014/ and if you are still unsure https://stackoverflow.com/q/27973009/1611058

Answer (score 0):

You do so by using facebook's open graph meta tags. Take a look here:
http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: Thank you, but that does not address the problem of sharing