# Is Facebook sharer.php endpoint NOT deprecated anymore?

Tags: facebook-sharer

Is Facebook sharer.php endpoint NOT deprecated anymore ?

I have been doing a lot of digging and researching on whether OR not , we can still use the Facebook share dialog URL for sharing :
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]

But, the official Facebook docs DO NOT reference it anywhere.

Facebook encourages developers to use the more modern Share Dialog that can be invoked using the JavaScript SDK or using a URL link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)

But this will require developers to register a Facebook App ID.

Therefore, it is easier to use the sharer.php approach. But, want to know if it is still safe to use sharer.php without the functionality breaking in the near future.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post from January 2014](http://www.joshuawinn.com/facebooks-sharer-php-longer-deprecated-2014/) (which points to [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)), `sharer.php` is officially no-longer deprecated.

I couldn't find the text they quoted in the documentation they linked to, but when I hover over the "Share" sample button on the documentation page the URL they are using -- it pops up in the lower left-hand corner of Firefox -- is the `sharer.php` URL.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20987387/225292), which gives the same information as the above post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @paul. During my online research for the sharer.php endpoint, I did review the links you mentioned in your comment above. But, what I am unclear about is the following :- The post you mention points to the [Share Button documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) and when you hover over the "Share" sample button in this documentation, it pops the sharer.php URL. But, it's not a simple sharer.php endpoint. It requires an app_id as a query string parameter. So, does this mean we have to now register a Facebook App ID ?

Comment: @abhi Good question, that detail had escaped me. I asked the person (where I work) who had tested uploading some sample images using this method and they said they'd just used the URL parameter of the `sharer.php` page, nothing else. So it looks like you don't need an app ID to post using this method.

Comment: Thanks @paul for the confirmation. One final followup question: On the [Facebook Changelog(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) link, they mention that the v1.0 of the API will be deprecated on April 30, 2015. Do you know how this date affects sharer.php endpoint OR any other Sharing capabilities of Facebook? It does NOT say anything in the "Changes from v1.0 to v2.0" section. But, I want to be sure.

Comment: @abhi I do not know what the status of `sharer.php` will be after the deprecation date. I hope it's still around for a long while, because that's what we're planning on switching to from v1.0 of the API. As to other sharing capabilities: I don't know, Facebook isn't something I spend my spare time reading up on ;)