# Facebook meta tag added, but link share on Facebook doesn't show

Tags: php, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-sharer

I have read and follow: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images), but the problem still exist.

My site is http://crossrt.net/election2013 and code below is added to  tag.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="General Election 13 unofficial website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://crossrt.net/election2013"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://crossrt.net/election2013/images/icon.png"/>
```

and the Facebook show me:
[image]

**but when i share my url on Facebook, nothing is show:**

[image]

Comment: Try to modify your html tag by adding the attribute : prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#". (http://ogp.me/)

Comment: Thx @RafH the title and description is display now, but the image still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this had been past about 22 days, but now only answer to this question. Perhaps the answer can help for someone. Following is the current meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="General Election 13 unofficial website"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Unofficial website of election" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://crossrt.net/election2013/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://crossrt.net/election2013/images/icon.jpg"/>
```

**What mistake I make in this question is that I use PNG transparent image as the og:image, so now I have a new JPG to replace it.**

I know this is quite stupid, but it does fix my problem. Everything works well now.