# The image to show when a web page is shared in facebook

Tags: facebook, html

I've a web page and I want to share it in facebook but the image shown is not ok. 
In the HTML code of the web I have:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/img/logo2.png" rel="image_src" />
```

In the options to select the image, there are other images, but not `logo2.png`
I've tried to delete facebook cache with [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), but the result is the same.

Edit:

If I add `?v=1` to the end the URL when I share it, the logo option is shown. It means that facebook debugger is not deleting the cache.
Also, I want that the logo image be the first option.

Can you help me?

Solved:

```
<!-- facebook tags -->
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/img/logo.png"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com">   
<meta property="og:title" content="Portfolio | web">    
<meta property="og:description" content="Portfolio">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may be using the wrong tag. I haven't done this in a while, but I believe that it should be a `<meta` tag with a `property="og:image"` and then content set to your image. The following (really old) question addresses this issue/conforms to what I remember: [How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Let me know if it works :)