# Force og:image to allow only one thumbnail

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

This og tag displays the proper image but it also shows two other thumbnails.

```
<meta property="og:image"content="http://www.merckengage.com/media/images/icons/merckengage.png" />
```

Is there a way to tell Facebook to only use one image? Currently it shows this image and randomly selects 2 more.

This image has been removed from our server, but it is cached by Facebook and appears as a thumbnail option when sharing.

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBTn6AE6mzj1fWr&w=100&h=100&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.merckengage.com%2Fmedia%2Fimages%2Flanding_page%2Fkit_oa.jpg&cfs=1&upscale
```

I have seen similar threads regarding this, but none of the suggestions posted will stop this image from showing up.

- I have changed the og:image url
- I have scraped the site with the debugger
- The image is 200x200

Is this happening because someone is using this image to share the site?
This image is no longer used and needs to be removed.

Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the page URL you are trying to share?

Comment: Sure, www.merckengage.com. Thanks

Comment: To answer your first question on whether it is possible to force Facebook use only one thumbnail without giving any other option, I don't think that's possible. To understand the whole process, refer the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/842065

To answer your second question, the images might be cached but however, the OG scrap with the debugger should update the cache. It didn't because, there is an image reference inside the HTML.
    <div id="kit_content_right">
      <img src="/media/images/landing_page/kit_oa.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

Comment: Also, I happen to read another post which says to use a fbrefresh parameter to refresh the cache. Though I have not personally needed the param to refresh it, it is ok you try as plenty of others have: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7695273/842065

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your feedback. The image reference to the "kit_oa.jpg" is the image that is showing up. But that image is no longer on our server. Does that mean it will still be used by Facebook? Just in case, I will remove any references to the image. Once again thanks.