# Custom image for facebook link sharer

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

Using graph API, I can set a custom image to be displayed when sharing link from my app. But, when a user shares a link of my website manually, a random image of my website comes in rather than my logo. So, is there a meta tag or something using which I can set a custom image as the image to be displayed in the link description box of facebook? Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to add are the [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) tags so that Facebook can parse your website more easily than its default parsing. The `<meta>` tags required are

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Page's Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourwebsite/article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourwebsite/images/displayImage.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Anvesh. I applied your suggestion, but in my case it is not working, as it should.

If I post my link page to the wall, it's ok, the image is showing. But if I post via url share/sharer.php, image is hidden, except on some web image host like imagilive.com (weird).
But, anyway, after posting the page url in the facebook debugger, all I did which failed before, is done with success.
I can handle the issue this way, but I have to do it with every page. Just imagine you have a photo gallery with each image shareable.
I need a better solution or a fix.