# How to tell facebook to use a specific thumbnail for sharing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get Facebook to

- use ONLY a specific image in a shared post
- or prevent other images from being used for sharing
- or at least set the specified image to appear first for selection?

These are my og:tags, but when sharing that page, FB proposes the image specified in og:image only as the second thumbnail - along with a banner and a logo from the footer :-(

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />       
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.ch/1231/testveranstaltung"/>       
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="www.example.ch" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Testveranstaltung" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="01.02.2014, 20:00 &mdash; Testtitel" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.ch/_upload/image/medium/i_20130918-075311-469.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="150" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="249" />
```

Comment: I'm aware there's a post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images that covers a lot of this, but it features older solutions as well and I can't see my issue there

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it: the image has to have a minimum size of 200px for the og:image tag to work.

Comment: If you land here with the same issue, don't forget to reset the fb cache on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ before testing