# Add image to facebook share

Tags: html, facebook, share

I'm trying to add an image to page share via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/
However, I can't seem to find how can I add an image to the facebook share post

Comment: Facebook uses open-graph meta tags to decide, which images it shows in the dialog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As rightly commented by demrks, Facebook uses [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta tags.

For your specific problem, you can use the `og:image` meta tag,

```
<meta name='og:image' content='path'>
```

Replace path with the path to where your image is.

You can check how your url appears on the timeline by using the [Facebook url debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Answer (score 4):

The Nov 18, 2013 answer is deprecated. The current answer according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/bookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```