# Using Open Graph for Facebook link sharing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've set up some OG meta data on my site so that when sharing a link, it displays a nice logo which I have created specifically for Facebook (it's square on a nice coloured background so it looks good on the site.)

However with this in place I am now no longer able to choose any other image. I was hoping for the logo to be the default but for the link sharing to still allow me to scroll through thumbnails from the page. Now it just gives me the option for the logo and nothing else.

Is it possible to set both a specific `og:image` and still have access to the thumbnails functionality on Facebook?

Here is my metadata:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysitehere.com/images/oglogo2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You find your answer here:

[How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Quote: *"You just need to add multiple image meta tags in the order you want them to appear in. The user will then be presented with an image selector dialog."*

Comment: So it is not possible to pull images from the page then? It's either set them all, or only pull from the page...

Comment: You can put multiple og:image tags, put the one you like best first and then the rest below. Facebook is far from ideal.