# Facebook not showing photos (joomla - sgiplus)

Tags: facebook, image, joomla, share, facebook-opengraph

quick question:
one tiny prob i have is when i try to share a page from my site on facebook (for example:http://pent-house.co.il/index.php/sale/52-2013-12-12-13-41-40), i cannot see thumbnails for the gallery. i see only the logo :\

is there any way that i can share the photos throw facebook?

thank you very much and have a damm nice day! XD

i wanted to shar a pic but i dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set an `og:image` meta tag like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="THE LINK TO YOUR IMAGE"/>
```

In the `<head>` of your document otherwise facebook bot uses (usualy) the biggest images he can fin. On the example page you linked to the biggest one is the logo.

Once you have set the `og:image` meta tag don't forget to delete facebook's cache by entering your page url on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) so you can see the modifications you make.

More information about thos meta tags and open graph [here](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags)

Comment: ty man! will i need to create a meta tag for each img or can i make this take for the img folder?

Comment: You will have to create an og:image meta tag for each image see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images